# How to underclock my graphic card with software

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

I need to underclock my graphic card. Is there any easy way?
My graphic card is nvidia gtx 850m.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a program called MSI Afterburner. It is mostly used to overclock video cards but you can also underclock your video card with it.

Here is a video on how to overclock/underclock your video card with MSI Afterburner: [How to Easily Over/Underclock Graphics Card - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ux1EJvc_10)

In case the youtube link ever breaks.

In the MSI Afterburner software you have the Core Clock Mhz, Memory Clock Mhz and Shader Clock Mhz. By reducing the values you are basically letting them run slower which can be seen as underclocking your video card. To set the video card to these settings you would first have to press Apply. I wouldn't really touch the voltage slider as it Could damage your card really badly and even your whole pc. Its recommended to go very slowly change values by a little at a time and check to see if your pc still runs fine. In case you ever want to Overclock your Video Card you would have to actually increase the settings. If you want to go pretty high with your overclocking you would have to touch the voltage eventually to make sure it has enough power to run at a certain Mhz. (I do not recommend this unless you really know what you are doing)

Comment: Thanks for offering to help SkyRamon. It is usually best to give the synopsis on links to other websites, that way if the link ever breaks, the content of the answer is still valid. Its worth mentioning how to achieve an underclock using afterburner. Thanks

Comment: @Lister Thanks I didn't think about that. I've added a brief description of the video incase the link dies. I hope this is more helpful.